# Faulted backtracking in Maze Java

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, maze

The task is to write a program that would use a prepared configuration of a maze as an input, determine if the maze solvable and, if so, draws it with the path in green. For drawing, I'm using a library, provided by our professors. My program determines "solvalability" correctly but when it comes to drawing it looks like my backtracking algorithm keeps record of all possible steps, including those that lead to a dead end.

I'm using a typical backtracking template that makes use of all visited cells that are then set to true in a boolean 2D array. The recursive function stops when the destination point is reached from the starting point. I return when I'm stuck at the maze wall, get in a dead end (i.e. maze[row][col] == 0) and I can walk only on the cells that I haven't visited yet. The [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E73nB.png) of a resulted maze is attached.

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me understand why the `visited` matrix does not store the walkable path correctly.

Here's the code:

```
import gdp.stdlib.StdDraw;

public class MazeSolver {

    public static boolean solve(int[][] maze, int row, int col) {
        // destination point coordinates
        int startRow = row;
        int startCol = col;
        
        //declare and initialize the filed visited, identical to the size of the maze
        //to keep track of moves
        boolean [][] visited = new boolean [maze.length][maze[0].length];
        for (int r=0; r<visited.length; r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<visited[0].length; c++)
                visited[r][c] = false;
        }
        
        boolean [][] mazeSolved = solveMaze(maze, visited, startRow, startCol);
        if (mazeSolved[maze.length-1][0]) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mazeSolved.length; i++ ) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mazeSolved.length; j++) {
                    if (mazeSolved[i][j])
                        maze[i][j] = 2;
                }
            }
            printMaze(visited);
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public static boolean [][] solveMaze(int[][] maze, boolean [][]visited, int row, int col) {
        //starting point coordinates
        int finishRow = maze.length-1;
        int finishCol = maze[maze.length-1][0];
        
        //four moves in the following order: up, down, right, left
        int [] moveRow = {-1, 1, 0, 0};
        int [] moveCol = {0, 0, 1, -1};
        
        if (row == finishRow && col == finishCol) {
            return visited;
        }
        
        else {
            for (int move = 0; move < moveRow.length; move++) {
                int nxt_row = row + moveRow[move];
                int nxt_col = col + moveCol[move];
                if (isMovePossible(maze, visited, nxt_row, nxt_col)) {
                    visited[nxt_row][nxt_col] = true;
                    solveMaze(maze, visited, nxt_row, nxt_col);
                    visited[row][col] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return visited;
    }

    public static int[][] rotateClockWise(int[][] matrix) {
         int size = matrix.length;
         int[][] ret = new int[size][size];

         for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
          for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) 
           ret[i][j] = matrix[size - j - 1][i]; //***

         return ret;
    }
    
    public static void draw(int[][] maze) {
        int maze_side = maze.length;
        StdDraw.setXscale(-1, maze_side + 1);
        StdDraw.setYscale(-1, maze_side + 1);
        
        //draw the frame
        StdDraw.line(0, 0, 0, maze_side);
        StdDraw.line(0, maze_side, maze_side, maze_side);
        StdDraw.line(maze_side, maze_side, maze_side, 0);
        StdDraw.line(0, maze_side, 0, 0);
        
        int [][]rotatedMaze = rotateClockWise(maze);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rotatedMaze.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rotatedMaze.length; j++) {
                if (rotatedMaze[i][j] == 0) {
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GRAY);
                }
                else if (rotatedMaze[i][j] == 1) {
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.WHITE);
                }
                else if (rotatedMaze[i][j] == 2) {
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
                }
                else if (rotatedMaze[i][j] == 3) {
                    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
                }
                StdDraw.filledSquare(i+0.5, j+0.5, 0.5);
            }
        }
        //draw lines
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
        for (int i = 0; i < maze_side; i++) {
            StdDraw.line(0, i, maze_side, i);
            StdDraw.line(i, 0, i, maze_side);
        }
    }
    
    //check if the next move is not out of bounds of the maze field and not a dead end
    public static boolean isMovePossible(int [][] maze, boolean [][] visited, int nxtRow, int nxtCol) {
        if ((nxtRow >= 0) && (nxtRow < maze.length) && (nxtCol >= 0) && (nxtCol < maze.length) && (maze[nxtRow][nxtCol] != 0) && (!visited[nxtRow][nxtCol]))
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
    
    static void printMaze(int[][] maze) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int[] row : maze) {
            for (int field : row) {
                System.out.print(field + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    static void printMaze(boolean[][] maze) {
        System.out.println();
        for (boolean[] row : maze) {
            for (boolean field : row) {
                System.out.print(field + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] maze_1 = new int[][] {
            { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };
        System.out.println(solve(maze_1, 0, maze_1.length-1));
        
        draw(maze_1);
    }
}
```